# Android two column (list view) linear layout with auto width for left column

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal is to achieve the following layout with a title (left), figure (right) and progress bar (below).

[image: layout goal]

I want the title description to break on new lines once it has filled the space and not overflow to the right (figure).

The closest I have come to this is by using a GridLayout as a child of a LinearLayout.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- top row -->
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/budget_listItem_title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            tools:text="foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/budget_listItem_remaining"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="1000"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>

    </GridLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="50"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when the description is too long, it pushes the figure off the screen;

[image]

So, ignoring the actual style/theme, what is the correct way to achieve this layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/budget_listItem_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/budget_listItem_remaining"
        tools:text="foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/budget_listItem_remaining"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:text="1000" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/budget_listItem_title"
        android:progress="50" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I used a Relative Layout because, as you may be able to tell by the name, it allows us to place elements relative to one another. In this instance we want the title to be to the left of the remaining value and aligned with the edge of the top left corner of the parent.